# "ExcelReaderFactory.cs not found" Error

Tags: c#, nuget, exceldatareader

I've downloaded ExcelDataReader from the Visual Studio Package Manager Console and followed the C# instructions on its Code Plex page http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/, but, during run-time, I get an "ExcelReaderFactory.cs not found" message when the code fails at the ExcelReaderFactory.  The entirety of my code block is below.

I've tried removing and reinstalling the Nuget package and searching for hours, coming upon an answer from this site: [ExcelReaderFactory.cs not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26391563/excelreaderfactory-cs-not-found).  I tried catching a possible exception, but none was caught in my code.  Is the exception only in the ExcelDataReader source code, to which I do not have access, and not in my code?  What is the solution to this error?  Thanks very much in advance.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadForecasts(HttpPostedFileBase ForecastsFile)
{
     try
     {
          string myPath = "C:\\Uploads\\" + ForecastsFile.FileName;
          ForecastsFile.SaveAs(myPath);
          System.IO.FileStream stream = System.IO.File.Open(myPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

          IExcelDataReader ForecastsReader = myPath.Contains(".xlsx")
               ? Excel.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream)
               : Excel.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
     }
}
```

Comment: Set a break point on Console.WriteLine and see if it hits it in Debug mode.  Then mouse over the ex variable to see the message.  Or add a Console.Read() to the end of your program so the window stays open.

Comment: Thanks TommyGunn32.  I moved a break point from the IExcelDataReader to the WriteLine, which shows the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.  Is the ForecastsReader null even though myPath and stream appear to contain data when mousing over them and the ForecastsReader seems to be initialized in much the same manner as in the Code Plex link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens to me as well. There isn't an exception being thrown necessarily, and honestly, as long as you don't try to step into the ExcelDataReader functions, it won't hurt anything.

In other words, set a breakpoint after the ExcelDataReader code, and just click `Continue` and it'll continue just fine. Hope this helps. It is trying to step into the DLL, but it can't. Just continue over it and it'll move on without throwing that error.

Comment: Thanks Ben Holland.  This explanation appears to be correct.  After adding more logic described in the Code Plex link, the IExcelDataReader object is, in fact, storing the input data for later manipulation in a Data Set.  It's uncomfortable seeing an an error that's not really an error, but it doesn't seem to be affecting the end result in any way.